# FullScreen WebView

Tags: java, android, web, view, constraints

Im trying to create a web view that enables it to fill the whole screen if the toolbar is gone. The code I used came up with no errors but doesn't display what I want rather its smaller then it was prior and am wondering if there is a better way or a more in-depth way.

The code I am using is as follows

```
    mToolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);


    if(mToolbar.getVisibility() == View.GONE){
        int mTb = 0;
        mWebView.requestLayout();
        mWebView.getLayoutParams().height = 567;
    }
```

I would like a more complex solution for reasons that I haven't reached yet in production

Comment: change this 567 to matchparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in xml write like this

```
<WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

and remove this in java code

```
if(mToolbar.getVisibility() == View.GONE){
        int mTb = 0;
        mWebView.requestLayout();
        mWebView.getLayoutParams().height = 567;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

dynamically you can fit `Webview` to screen using

```
 if(mToolbar.getVisibility() == View.GONE){
        int mTb = 0;
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        mWebView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);


        mWebView.requestLayout();
    }
```